# How can I extract all values in a database that start with the same letters as user input?

Tags: php, sql

So I'm working on a stock quotes page, and in the "Find Symbol page", the user enters the symbol for a company and any symbols stored in the database that start with the exact same letters as user input will be output onto the table.

SOLVED- ANSWER BELOW

Comment: You are assigning the first Row, right after the `}else{` then you overwrite it when you iterate with the `while` loop.  You never use the first row, so when you have only 1 row, you have none. ( The while loop does not reset the result set back to 0 ) You also have a bunch of other minor issues.  I outlined them in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your input in lowercase and it is stored in  upper case

So change your query to convert the string into upper and then search
It is better to have upper in both sides of the where clause.

```
$query = "SELECT symSymbol, symName FROM symbols " .
"WHERE upper(symSymbol) LIKE '%".strtoupper($strSymbol)."%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this mess all about?  Please see my comments in your code.

```
if(!$result)
{
    print "Invalid Query Result<br />\n";
}
else
{
    //============ This line is your main issue ============
    $row = @$result->fetch_assoc(); //<-- pulling a row here advances the 
    //data set to row #2 (you never use the data from this row)
    //======================================================
    print "<table border='3' >\n";
    print "<tr><th>Symbol</th>"            
    . "<th>Company Name</th>"            
    . "<th>Quotes Page</th"  //<<--- unclosed </th>
    . "<tr><th>History Page</th></tr>\n";  //<<--- misplaced <tr>
}//<<--- end if($result) block,
 /*
  anything below this is outside of the scope of the check for the result, 
  this will give you partial HTML and errors in the event of $result = false
 */

 /*
   because, you already advanced the dataset by one row, the loop starts on row 2
   If you only had 1 row in your result set, then nothing is output from this block
   While loops do not rewind, like a foreach ( besides I don't think you can rewind the DB result cursor )         
 */
 while($row = @$result->fetch_assoc())  
 {
 extract($row); //<<--- avoid using this as it pollutes the scope, also where exactly are you using these variables it creates

print "<tr>";
print "<td>{$row["symSymbol"]}</td>";
print "<td align='right'>{$symName}</td>";
print "<td><a href=\"quotes.php?Name=" . $row["symSymbol"]. "\"> Quotes Page</a></td>";
 print "<td><a href=\"history.php?Name=" . $row["symSymbol"]. "\"> History Page</a></td>";



 print "</tr>\n";
 }
 print "</table>\n";
```

Lets start by cleaning that up

```
if(!$result){
    print "Invalid Query Result<br />\n";
}else{
    print "<table border='3' >\n";
      /*
         don't be afraid to indent or format things in a way that helps
         keep track of the tags.  Not like the "tab" police are going to
         bust you for using all the tabs up.
       */
    print "<tr>";
           print "<th>Symbol</th>"            
            . "<th>Company Name</th>"            
            . "<th>Quotes Page</th>"
            . "<th>History Page</th>\n";
    print "</tr>\n";

    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        /*
           Try to use a consistent style for outputting, if possible.
        */
        print "<tr>";
            print "<td>{$row["symSymbol"]}</td>"
                . "<td align='right'>{$symName}</td>"
                . "<td><a href=\"quotes.php?Name=" . $row["symSymbol"]. "\"> Quotes Page</a></td>"
                . "<td><a href=\"history.php?Name=" . $row["symSymbol"]. "\"> History Page</a></td>\n";
        print "</tr>\n";
    }

    print "</table>\n";
 }
```

You are basically throwing away the first row of your result set. When you call this `..}else{ $row = @$result->fetch_assoc(); ..` you pull out the first row and move the internal pointer to row #2.  Not only do you never use this data, but you overwrite `$row` with the value assigned in the `while` loop.  Now `while` loops do not rewind back to the first result, so you pull row #2 and overwrite `$row` or you overwrite it with `false`.  This is why when you have one match, you get none.

Some other thing to mention:

- See how much clearer and concise my code is, well organized easy to read.  Readability is the most important thing when coding ( IMO ).
- Scope, keep the `$result` stuff inside the if block.  If you don't do this then you're gonna have a bunch of errors, and invalid HTML.
- Don't assign something if you are not gonna use it.  While I understand, I was just "testing" that or "working" this out. That's all fine, but the first thing you should do when you have an issue, is go though your code, organize it and clean it up.  Remove any "Fragments" from refactoring, and add comments to anything that is not clear just looking at the code it self.
- Avoid using `extract` it pollutes your variable scope.  That means you could overwite a variable without realizing it.

For example, say you have this code:

```
  $name = 'John';
   ... bunch of other code ..
  extract( $row );
   ... more code ...
  echo $name;  //outputs Tom
```

Now without being able to see the value of `$row` directly, you have no way to know that's what happened just by looking at the code. It's just a bad practice (IMO) to use it, because you don't want to use `$row['name']`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful! Yeah my code was a mess, this helped me understand it a lot better.

Comment: Sure it was no problem, I been coding like 6 years I can do that I'n my sleep .  I probably write a few thousand lines of code a day.  Gets pretty easy to spot problems.